# After Installing SSMA for oracle, still showing me installer not app

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I have installed SSMA for Oracle, in order to migrate my data from oracle to MYSQL Server, But after installation, app is not opening, and it's continously showing me same alert message of instances.

Can someone please help me on this?

Check this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't think you finished writing this question. Can you add the error message and more info on what's happening?

Comment: @KasiaGogolek i've added the forgotten image link